# Change Key for a SortedList

Tags: c#, sortedlist

I need a Sorted list, but after I remove an item from the list I then need to adjust the keys of the other items before adding new items to the list.

You are not allowed to change the key for the items in a "SortedList".

What tool would be best for doing this.

Example code

```
  timedEvQue.Add(3, "First");
  timedEvQue.Add(7, "Second");
  timedEvQue.Add(9, "Third");
  int decAmnt = (int)timedEvQue.Keys[0];
  timedEvQue.RemoveAt(0);

  for (int i = 0; i < timedEvQue.Count; ++i)
  {
    timedEvQue.Keys[i] = timedEvQue.Keys[i] - decAmnt; //runtime error here
  }

  timedEvQue.Add(5, "Forth");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't typically a change key operation for dictionary/hash map type data structures as they would essentially just remove and add the item again. So just remove and add the item back.

```
timedEvQue.Add(3, "First");
timedEvQue.Add(7, "Second");
timedEvQue.Add(9, "Third");
int decAmnt = (int)timedEvQue.Keys[0];
timedEvQue.RemoveAt(0);

for (int i = 0; i < timedEvQue.Count; ++i)
{
    int oldKey = timedEvQue.Keys[i];
    string val = timedEvQue[oldKey];
    int newKey = oldKey - decAmnt;
    timedEvQue.Remove(oldKey);
    timedEvQue.Add(newKey, val);
}

timedEvQue.Add(5, "Forth");
```

Comment: There is going to be lots of items, and I am afraid this will slow it down to much.

Comment: I suspect that `SortedList` might not be the right answer for what you want. I wrote a blog post about the running times of the .NET data structures which you might find helpful. I suggest you check that out and if you're still struggling ask another question outlining the problem and what operations you need the data structure to be fast with. http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2013/02/what-data-structure-net-collections-use.html

Comment: I am not going to be looking up very many items, so lookup speeds are not as much of an issue.  However, it would be nice to have more than one Key.  Is there something better that will allow changing the key value and more than one key?

Comment: Well, a `Lookup` allows you to store multiple items against a key, it's basically just a hash map. Again there is no change key but add and remove operations typically run in constant time so it should be way faster than the `SortedList`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the Lookup.